# Showing that $\frac{aA+bB+cC}{a+b+c}\geq\frac\pi3$ for $A$, $B$, $C$ the angles, and $a$, $b$, $c$ the sides, of a triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

> Let $A,B,C$ be the magnitude (in radians) of the three angles of a triangle, and let $a,b,c$ be the lengths of the sides opposite to these angles respectively. Prove that $$\frac{aA+bB+cC}{a+b+c}\geq\frac\pi3$$

**Attempt:**

WLOG, $A\geq B\geq C$.

As $A+B+C=\pi$, this implies $\frac{A+B+C}3=\frac\pi3$. We also note that by sine rule: $$\frac a{\sin A}=\frac b{\sin B}=\frac c{\sin C}=d$$

for some $d$. This implies $a=d\sin A$, $b=d\sin B$, $c=\sin C$. Using these substitutions:

$$\frac{Ad\sin A+Bd\sin B+Cd\sin C}{d\sin A+d\sin B+d\sin C}\geq\frac{A+B+C}3$$

$$A\sin A+B\sin B+C\sin C\geq\frac{A+B+C}3(\sin A+\sin B+\sin C)$$

$$\frac{A\sin A+B\sin B+C\sin C}3\geq\frac{A+B+C}3\frac{\sin A+\sin B+\sin C}3$$

If we assume $A,B,C\leq\frac\pi2$, then we note that in the interval $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$, $\sin x$ is monotonically increasing, hence $\sin A\geq\sin B\geq\sin C$. Then by Chebyshev's inequality, the above inequality is true.

But if $A>\frac\pi2$, it is not necessarily true that $\sin A\geq\sin B\geq\sin C$, and I cannot apply Chebyshev's inequality! What should I do in such a case?

I did wonder if I could apply Jensen's inequality, but the function $x\sin x$ has an inflection point in the interval $[0,\pi]$ so I could not use it.

Comment: Tchebechev's inequality can be used if $p,q,r$ and $a,b,c$ are ordered simililarly, Namely, if $p\ge q \ge r$ and $a\ge b\ ge c$ then $ap+bq+cr \ge (a+b+c)(p+q+r)/3$. $\sin x>0$ in a triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a \geqslant b \geqslant c,$ then $A \geqslant B \geqslant C.$ By the Rearrangement inequality, we have
$$3(aA+bB+cC) \geqslant (A+B+C)(a+b+c) = \pi(a+b+c),$$
or
$$\dfrac{aA+bB+cC}{a+b+c} \geqslant\frac{\pi}{3}.$$

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you mean [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)? Great answer though.

Comment: @Kyky No, [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) has nothing to do with variance and probability bound.  It can be used to prove [Chebyshev's sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality) which is essentially what is done here.

Comment: @user10354138 Oops, linked to the wrong inequality.